# Are my motorcycle handlebars twisted?

Tags: motorcycle, handlebars

I'm a learner rider. My motorcycle (110 cc, 117 Kg weight) fell down on left side while I was parking. The road (or call it street) was dirt road. Not to be confused with gravel road.

I mean it was just little soil and tiny bit grass. It *wasn't* like desert sand. I just mean it wasn't so hard road when compared to paved or even gravel road. You can assume it fell in a lawn/garden.

So when the bike fell down, and I could see the left handle grip had soil on it, the side mirror also had soil on it and 2 tiny scratches on visor and left indicator on front side. No other noticeable damage I could find.

Now I *might* be overthinking.

But I have often seen videos on YouTube with bent handlebars and how they fix it. But they are very obvious.

So I'm thinking could this fall make my handlebar bent or damaged too?

---

I personally didn't notice any difference when I rode after that. And it looked straight to me as it was before when I was holding it straight. Even the front wheel was straight like before.

Given all that, how likely is handlebar bend/twist after a lightweight motorcycle gently falls down while parking on not so hard surface?

**And how to identify if it is actually bent? I mean are there some known techniques to identify most common handlebar bent problems? Would you notice a bent/twisted handlebar somehow?**

(Preferably techniques/ideas where I don't need to open/unscrew the parts of my motorcycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small fall will many times result only in scratches and dirt, but no mechanical damage.

If you cannot *see* a misalignment, and you cannot *feel* a difference in the riding, then it's most likely the bars are not bent or pushed out of position.

Source: 48 years of motorcycle riding, including some low-speed falls.